# User defined types with dynamic size in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays, user-defined-types

I want to define a new data type consisting of an array with a size inputted by the user. For example if the user inputs 128, then my program should make a new type which is basically an array of 16 bytes. This structure's definition needs to be global since I am going to use that type thereafter in my program. It is necessary to have a dynamic size for this structure because I will have a HUGE database populated by that type of variables in the end.

The code I have right now is:

```
struct user_defined_integer;
.
.
.
void def_type(int num_bits)
{
    extern struct user_defined_integer 
    {
             int val[num_bits/sizeof(int)];
    };

return;

}
```

(which is not working)

The closest thing to my question, I have found, is in here:
[I need to make a global array in C with a size inputted by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830507/i-need-to-make-a-global-array-in-c-with-a-size-inputted-by-the-user)
(Which is not helpful)

Is there a way to do this, so that my structure is recognized in the whole file?

Comment: There's no way the code above would compile, structures defined within a function have local scope; ain't no workin' round that.

Comment: Won't work. Use malloc and a length field.

Comment: note that you need to round the result of the division up or make sure that `num_bits` is divisible by `sizeof(int)`, otherwise you won't have space to store the last bits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing:

```
extern struct user_defined_integer 
{
         int val[num_bits/sizeof(int)];
};
```

You should get the warning:

```
warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
```

because you have an empty declaration. `extern` does not apply to `user_defined_integer`, but rather the variable that comes *after* it. Secondly, this won't work anyway because a struct that contains a variable length array can't have any linkage.

```
error: object with variably modified type must have no linkage
```

Even so, variable length arrays allocate storage at the point of declaration. You should instead opt for dynamic memory.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int num_bits;
    int* val;
} user_defined_integer;

void set_val(user_defined_integer* udi, int num_bits)
{
    udi->num_bits = num_bits;
    udi->val = malloc(num_bits/sizeof(int));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a VLA member, as asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559558/one-element-array-in-struct). Basically, you declare a `struct` with a size field and one element's worth of storage as last member, and over-allocate it.

Imported from that question :

```
typedef struct Bitmapset {
    int nwords;
    uint32 words[1];
} Bitmapset;

Bitmapset *allocate(int n) {
    Bitmapset *p = malloc(offsetof(Bitmapset, words) + n * sizeof *p->words);
    p->nwords = n;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: flexible array members are a cleaner way to achieve that.

Comment: In C99, yes. Before that, you have no choice but to overflow a one-length array.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to define a new data type consisting of an array with a size inputted by the user. For example if the user inputs 128, then my program should make a new type which is basically an array of 16 bytes.

This is not possible in C, because C types are a *compile-time* thing and don't exist at all at *run-time*.

However, with a C99 conforming compiler, you might use flexible array member. You'll need a `struct` containing some members and ending with an array without any given dimension, e.g.

```
struct my_flex_st {
   unsigned size;
   int arr[]; // of size elements
};
```

Here is a way to allocate it:

```
struct my_flex_st *make_flex(unsigned siz) {
  struct my_flex_st* ptr 
    = malloc(sizeof(struct my_flex_st) + siz * sizeof(int));
  if (!ptr) { perror("malloc my_flex_st"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  ptr->size = siz;
  memset (ptr->arr, 0, siz*sizeof(int));
  return ptr;
}
```

Don't forget to `free`  it once you don't use it anymore.

Of course, you'll need to use *pointers* in your code. If you really want to have a global variable, declare it as e.g.

```
extern struct my_flex_st* my_glob_ptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>
struct user_defined_integer
{
        int *val;
}user_int;
void memory_allocate(int num_bit)
{
        int result;
        result = (num_bit+CHAR_BIT-1)/CHAR_BIT; // since 8 bit =1 byte
        user_int.val=malloc(result*sizeof(int));
        if(user_int.val == NULL){
        printf("Failed to allocate memory\n");
        return ;
        }
        else
        printf("Allocated %d bytes for val\n",result);
}
int main()
{
        int num_bit;
        printf("Enter the number of bits\n");
        scanf("%d",&num_bit);
        memory_allocate(num_bit);
        // do your stuff here

        free(user_int.val); // free the memory at the end;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `malloc` returns NULL, this program will crash... ;)

Comment: Add `#include <limits.h>` and replace `8` with `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: Change `num_bit/CHAR_BIT` to `(num_bit+CHAR_BIT-1)/CHAR_BIT` in order to support non `CHAR_BIT` multiple number of bits (for example, 13).

Comment: You may remove the `since 8 bit =1 byte` comment by now.

Comment: But change `int *val` to `char *val` and remove that `sizeof(int)` when calling `malloc`.