# Using malloc in function?

Tags: c, malloc

I am new to malloc. So I wanted to test this small code.
I'm getting the "segmentation fault error".

**EDIT: The problem was from not allocation char* name (Thanks to @Zack)
You can see what caused the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct info { char *name; } fileinfo;

void mal (fileinfo **ptr)
{   
if ((*ptr = (fileinfo*) malloc(3*sizeof(fileinfo))) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Memory allocating error #1\n");
    exit(1);
    }
//that what was causing the error - START
for (j = 0; j < 3; j += 1)
    {
    (*ptr)[j].name = (char*) malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
    }
//that what was causing the error - END
    strcpy(ptr[0]->name,"1. A\n");                        //line 13
    strcpy(ptr[1]->name,"2. B\n");
    strcpy(ptr[2]->name,"3. C\n");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
fileinfo *files;
int i;
mal(&files);                                             //line 22
for (i = 0; i < 3; i += 1)
{
    printf("name=%s\n",files[i].name);
}
free(files);
return 0;
}
```

Using valgrind:

```
==5751== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5751==    at 0x4006EB: mal (mal1.c:13)
==5751==    by 0x400747: main (mal1.c:22)
==5751== 
==5751== Invalid write of size 4
==5751==    at 0x4006EB: mal (mal1.c:13)
==5751==    by 0x400747: main (mal1.c:22)
==5751==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

What am I doing wrong??!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: `char *name` does not allocate space for a string.

Comment: If you are new to malloc then perhaps start by trying something without double pointers...

Comment: Another problem is that `ptr[0]->name` should be `(*ptr)[0].name`, etc.

Comment: @AhmadNourELDeen, `ptr[0].name = malloc(100);`

Comment: Yes, the problem is in allocation name. I made it name[10] and there was no error. So now, how to use malloc for (*name)? I can't get the right syntax.

Comment: @R Sahu, thanks but it didn't work: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: Your example and your code is useless, because you don't have much variation on the data. What if you had 4 names, not 3, what if some of the names was `"quite a long string like this or even more abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` ? Doing either change would break your code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I wrote this code only to test using malloc with pointers to pointers to structures. Simply, my real code is about 230 line. I had problems caused by passing pointers to functions and using malloc. When I return back to main, I can't use these pointers again! This code was not my target at all. I only used it to simulate my real code.I can tell you now that my 230-line code is working now because of this "useless code".

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: One more thing: I could easily delete my "useless question" but I didn't in case of if can help someone that has my same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you need to allocate ptr[i]->name before copying to it.  A pointer by itself points to some random area of memory.  To use it, you must get good memory that is safe and that is what malloc and calloc, and (new in C++) all do.  The example you gave is still a mess, and my correction isn't that great, but you get the idea that every pointer in C and C++ must be allocated from somewhere.  And, on the flipside, once you are done with the pointer, you have to free them.

```
void mal (fileinfo **ptr, int count)
{   
    if ((*ptr = (fileinfo*) malloc(count*sizeof(fileinfo))) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Memory allocating error #1\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       char buff[2];
       buff[0] = 'A' + i;
       buff[1] = 0;
       ptr[i]->name = malloc( 10 );
       strcpy(ptr[0]->name,"1. %s\n", buff);                        
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for all of this :)

Comment: I edited the question, you can see what I edited was easier. Thanks you for your help :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
void mal (fileinfo **ptr) {   
  if ((*ptr = malloc(3*sizeof(fileinfo))) == NULL) {
   perror("Memory allocating error #1\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (!(ptr[0]->name = strdup("1. A\n"))) 
    { perror("string 1"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};                      
  if (!(ptr[1]->name = strdup("2. B\n")))
    { perror("string 2"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};    
  if (!(ptr[2]->name = strdup("3. C\n")))
    { perror("string 3"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);} ;
}
```

BTW, it would be better to make it a function returning a pointer, like

```
 fileinfo* make() {
   fileinfo* ptr = malloc(3*sizeof(fileinfo)));
   if (!ptr) { perror("make fileinfo"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  if (!(ptr[0]->name = strdup("1. A\n"))) 
    { perror("string 1"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};                      
  if (!(ptr[1]->name = strdup("2. B\n")))
    { perror("string 2"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};    
  if (!(ptr[2]->name = strdup("3. C\n")))
    { perror("string 3"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);} ;
  return ptr;
 }
```

Then, you need a destructor function like

```
void destroy(fileinfo*ptr) {
  free (ptr[0]->name);
  free (ptr[1]->name);
  free (ptr[2]->name);
  free (ptr);
}
```

to be called instead of your `free` at the end of your `main`

Notice that your code is very ad hoc: the number (i.e. 3) of names is completely built-in. This is wrong design. At the very least, that constant should have been named:

```
 #define NB_FILES 3
```

Actually, a much better approach would be to declare your structure with a flexible array member:

```
typedef struct fileinfo_st { 
   unsigned nbfiles;
   char* filenames[]; 
} Fileinfo;
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25500162/841108) for more. You could even have a variadic function to make such structures.

```
FIleinfo *make(int, ...);
```

Which you would call like

```
Fileinfo* ptr = make (3, "abc","def","ghijklmnop");
```

or you could decide that that last variadic argument is `NULL`

BTW, read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You might be unlucky to have your program not crashing but still be very wrong. And compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and learn more how to use the `gdb` debugger and `valgrind`